# how can i set time value to 00:00:00 in the dateformat such as Tue Dec 28 17:36:28 IST 2010?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm using Java and
I'm trying the below piece of code

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(now1);
cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);  
java.util.Date yesterday = (Date) cal1.getTime();  
System.out.println(yesterday.toString());
java.sql.Timestamp yesterdayTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(tomorrow.getTime());
System.out.println(yesterdayTimestamp.toString());
```

which gives me the output as `Tue Dec 28 17:36:28 IST 2010`
Now I want to set the time in this to `00:00:00` then
`Tue Dec 28 17:36:28 IST 2010` will be `Tue Dec 28  00:00:00 IST 2010`

I'm not getting how to do this?

Comment: User Formatter. For example SimpleDateFormat. This link may help http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/

Answer (score 5):

If I have understand problem correctly you want to set time related fields to be set to 0.

```
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();  
        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        System.out.println(cal1.getTime());
```

**Output**

```
Wed Dec 29 00:00:00 IST 2010
```

Comment: You are welcomed to upvote AND/OR accept this as an answer as it is for you

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the individual elements of the time component.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int, int)

```
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just need  date , not time , you should use java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 1):

In your calendar you can set the respective fields to 0: `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)`.

Alternatively, you can use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which has the [`DateMidnight`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) class for that purpose.

Btw, as noted in the comments - use a formatter. [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for example. You should not rely on the `toString()` representation of an object.